# median regression line in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use ggplot to fit a median regression line. This uses the rq() function of the quantreg package. The data is the clouds data from the HSAUR3 package. This is my code:

```
seeding.no <- predict(rq(rainfall ~ sne, data = clouds, subset = seeding == "no"))
seeding.yes <- predict(rq(rainfall ~ sne, data = clouds, subset = seeding == "yes"))
clouds.predcit <- data.frame(Rainfall=clouds$rainfall, No=seeding.no, Yes=seeding.yes)

ggplot(clouds, aes(x=sne, y=rainfall, colour=clouds$seeding, shape=clouds$seeding)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) +
  labs(title="Rainfall vs S-Ne Criterion", x="S-Ne Criterion", y="Rainfall") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2)) +
  geom_line(color="blue",data=clouds.predcit, aes(x=No, y=Rainfall)) +
  geom_line(color="red",data=clouds.predcit, aes(x=Yes, y=Rainfall)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to get:

[image]

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used:

```
geom_quantile(quantiles = 0.5)
```

and got this to work. Didn't need to predict after all.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong geom I think, you'll have more luck using geom_smooth. This comes with a fair few options, but you likely want +geom_smooth(method="lm"). I can't get your code to run as is, even when installing the HSAUR3 package.

Try this

```
seeding.no <- predict(rq(rainfall ~ sne, data = clouds, subset = seeding == "no"))
seeding.yes <- predict(rq(rainfall ~ sne, data = clouds, subset = seeding == "yes"))
clouds.predcit <- data.frame(Rainfall=clouds$rainfall, No=seeding.no, Yes=seeding.yes)

ggplot(clouds, aes(x=sne, y=rainfall, colour=clouds$seeding, shape=clouds$seeding) + 
  geom_point(size=2) +
  labs(title="Rainfall vs S-Ne Criterion", x="S-Ne Criterion", y="Rainfall") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  theme_minimal()
```

also if you would like to rename your legend easily, just add *colour = "your legend title"* into the labs() argument.

Comment: Using method="lm" makes a linear regression model which uses mean, whereas I am looking to use a median regression model. Did you attach the clouds data? `data("clouds")`

Comment: my bad, you're right I misread your original post. The data is attached, is just cannot find the function "rq", i'm assuming its from the package "quantreg" . Using the quantreg package, I can get it to run without an error, I would use geom_quantile() instead of geom_smooth then. **edit** I see you've found the solution yourself already. Good work!